# intermediate values theorem and intervals

Tags: real-analysis

hi everbody i am trying to solve  this exercise in relation  with  intermediate values theorem:

let $f$ defined and continuous function in $[a,b]$ with $[a,b]\subseteq f([a,b])$.
Prove that $f(x)=x$ admits at least one solution in $[a,b]$

I am not sure how to deal with this theorem so I have no idea where to start. if someone could walk me through the process that would be great.

Comment: I ve'already tried to use g(x)=f(x)-x then say that g is a continuous function in [a,b] ,but i wasn't able to prove that g(a)*g(b)<o in case to say that it exist c in [a,b] then g(x)=0 and conclude f(x)=x

Comment: Hint: Note that $a\leq f(x)\leq b$ for each $x\in[a,b]$.

Answer (score 1):

Let $g(x)=f(x)-x$. Show that $g$ is continuous (so the Intermediate Value Theorem applies to $g$), and that $g(a)\ge0$, and $g(b)\le0$, and then...?

Comment: thank you for your participation Gerry Myerson , i tried to

Comment: use g(x) but i wasn't able to prove that g(a).g(b)<0

Comment: OK, but try to follow what I wrote, instead.

Comment: in fact I do not have any idea of how to show that g(a)>0 and g(b)<0

Comment: Well, what is $g(a)$?

Comment: I'd like if you don't have any probleme to walk me through the process with what you disassemble that g(a)>0 and g(b)<0

Comment: The first part of the process is to get $g(a)$. So: what is $g(a)$?

Comment: Have you given up? $g(x)=f(x)-x$, so, what is $g(a)$?

Comment: Earth to wuppertal ... come in, please ....